# Views Sort by Taxonomy with headers

Tags: views, theming

I have a bunch of nodes that are of the type expert. Expert nodes have a flexible sized list of expertise categories. So an expert would be a person, (Patrick McDougle, Patricia O'Connor …) and a expertise category would be (Autism, Aging, Bulimia …) Using Views 3 and Drupal 7 I would like to end up with something like this:

**Aging**
Patricia O'Connor

**Autism**
Patrick McDougle
Patricia O'Connor

**Bulimia**
Patrick McDougle
...

Is there a way to do this, without having to create my own views template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to add a view of taxonomy terms, and then add a relationship to the content. You'll also have to hide some fields and add a grouping field in the unformatted list settings. Details are below.

- Create a new view that shows "Taxonomy terms" of type "expert [vocabulary]" sorted by Unsorted
- Continue and edit
- Add a relationship under Advanced > Relationships
- Choose "Taxonomy term: Content with term" (Relate all content tagged with a term) & apply to all displays
- You'll now be able to add a field and the content will show up. Click add next to Fields and select the Content Title or whichever field the name is stored at.
- Uncheck "Create a Label" and apply.
- Click on Format > Settings, and select "Taxonomy term: Name" in the "Grouping field Nr.1" dropdown, and click Apply. This will create a heading of the taxonomy term.
- Hide the taxonomy terms from showing up extra times by clicking on the "Taxonomy term: Name" field, and click "Exclude from display."
- Uncheck "Link this field to its taxonomy term page" so that the taxonomy term is not linked to it's page.
- Save the view, and view the page.

Comment: Thank you very much @kent-bye, this was very helpful. Now to figure out how to do a list of the terms at the top with anchor links to the terms...

Comment: The requirement 'Views Sort by Taxonomy with headers' is clear but the steps given by you do not work for views with a single column table to display all the unique taxonomy terms of a (node) content-type that can contains a multiple term field. Spent more than a day trying to go by what you say.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by choosing Table in format, then group by expert category.

Comment: Fo that you need to be sure you have set "Use aggregation" to Yes in the view advanced > other options

Comment: Is there a non-tabular way to do it? This data isn't really semantically tabular.

Comment: Use aggregation is giving me a lot more to play with, thanks @MikaA. !

Comment: Pleased to help @PatrickJamesMcDougle

Comment: I still can't find a way to create the headers without using the table format.